# Reading of Excel File c#

Tags: c#, excel

[image]

Hi guys! I encountered a problem is that I have difficulty reading this Excel file into data grid view as shown above. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

These were my codes to read Excel file but there's a error that I have difficulty troubleshooting it.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
        Excel.Range ShtRange;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        OpenFileDialog filedlgExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
        filedlgExcel.Title = "Select file";
        filedlgExcel.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        filedlgExcel.FileName = txtFileName.Text;
        filedlgExcel.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        filedlgExcel.FilterIndex = 1;
        filedlgExcel.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (filedlgExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           workbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(filedlgExcel.FileName);
            NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
        ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange; //gives the used cells in sheet
        //Reading Excel file.
        //Creating dataTable to read the containt of the Sheet in File.

        //Set header name
        for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
        }
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        //store coumn names to array
        string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();

        //populate fields
        for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
            {
                dr[Cnum - 1] = (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        ExcelObj.Quit();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            string strEmployee = dr["Employee Name"].ToString();
            obj1 = new List<employeeschedule>();
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                string period = dr[i].ToString();
                string[] split = period.Split('–');
                employeeschedule es = new employeeschedule();
                string day = columnNames[i];
                if (split[0] == "REST")
                {
                    es.day = day;
                    es.startTime = "0000";
                    es.endTime = "0000";
                    es.restDay = "Yes";
                }
                if (split[0] == "OFF")
                {
                    es.day = day;
                    es.startTime = "0000";
                    es.endTime = "0000";
                    es.restDay = "Yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    es.day = day;
                    es.startTime = split[0];
                    es.endTime = split[1];
                    es.restDay = "No";
                }
                obj1.Add(es);
            }

            dict.Add(strEmployee, obj1);
            dgvEmployeeShift.DataSource = dt;
        }
            }
        }
```

The error falls on this part:

```
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
```

It states that "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".

Comment: First make sure dt is set and '.Columns != null'.
It seems to me that 'as Excel.Range' returns null and therefore null.Value2 returns the null reference exception.
If you already knew this, be more specific on what you want and what you tried.

Comment: I wanted the data inside the Excel to be viewed into the data grid view when I select the Excel file. Any examples on what you mean by Excel.Range and columns != null ?

Comment: the last line of code you posted contains ' as Excel.Range)'. 'as' converts to null if the conversion could not be made. Make sure it is not null. The same is for 'dt.Columns'. make sure both 'dt' and '.Columns' are initialized.

Comment: This is cool, but... do you always make screenshots with a camera? :D

Answer (score 1):

I love using Interop when automating Excel but for your requirement why not use `OleDb`? It is much faster than using Interop?

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyCon ;
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet ;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand ;

        //~~> Replace this with relevant file path
        MyCon = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Sample.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"");

        //~~> Replace this with the relevant sheet name
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyCon);

        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "MyTable");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

        //~~> Fill Dataset
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);

        //~~> Set Source
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
        MyCon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL not OleDb. how?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you meant by above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm misunderstand anything. Is your code suited for selecting any Excel file or a hard coded one that can only read a particular one you entered in the codes.

Comment: Yup. But it is an example of how to use oleDb. I am sure you can easily modify it to adapt in your code. For example instead of hardcoding the file name as I have done, simply use OFD for the input and then parse the filename :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ...........
Browses your local folder , picks up the excel ,displays in grid view.
Using oledb is what i suggest

private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfiledialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openfiledialog1.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox_path.Text = openfiledialog1.FileName;

```
        }


    }

    private void LoadExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string pathConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+textBox_path.Text+";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        string pathConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox_path.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathConn);

        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter mydataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from ["+textBox_sheet.Text+"$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        mydataadapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        conn.Close();
     }
```